# Download of mysql rpm unauthorized

Tags: centos, mysql, rpm

I've been using this website:

```
https://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/installing-mysql-5-7-on-centosredhatfedora/
```

as a basis for executing the following command:

```
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-7.noarch.rpm
```

However I get a unauthorized response when I do this. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web front-end for their download page makes you pinkie-promise that you are up to no good before downloading.  I would just download the RPM manually in a browser, and then keep it handy to `scp` to other hosts upon which you wish to install it.